# Fatal error: Cannot unset $this PHP 7.1

Tags: php, poo, php7

Me aparece el siguiente error en PHP: **Fatal error: Cannot unset $this** que hace referencia a este fragmento de código:

```
public function __destruct(){
    unset($this);
}
```

Esa linea la utilizo para destruir un objeto, en versiones anteriores de PHP funcionaba sin problemas pero ahora con PHP 7 me muestra ese error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ese error aparece al menos a partir de PHP 7.

De todos modos, ten en cuenta lo que dice el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php) sobre el método `destruct`:

> PHP 5 introduce un concepto de destructor similar al de otros
>   lenguajes orientados a objetos, tal como C++. **El método destructor
>   será llamado tan pronto como no hayan otras referencias a un objeto
>   determinado**, o en cualquier otra circunstancia de finalización.

Podemos decir que el método destructor no es tonto, él sabe que cuando es invocado es para destruir **ese objeto**, por lo que el uso de `$this` es redundante. En PHP 7 se dieron cuenta de ello y decidieron lanzar este mensaje de error cuando se invoque `unset($this)`, porque en realidad no tiene sentido hacerlo.

Por otra parte, sobre destruir un objeto con `unset` [el Manual dice lo siguiente](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php):

> No es posible remover `$this` dentro de un método de objeto a partir
>   de PHP 5.

#### ¿Entonces cómo destruyo un objeto?

En algunos casos, en PHP el objeto es destruido cuando el script termina (no hay ninguna referencia al objeto). Así ocurre por ejemplo con los objetos de conexión a la base de datos en PDO.

Si tú quieres destruir el objeto de manera explícita, debido a lo mencionado más arriba, a partir de PHP 5 el objeto será destruido como ocurre en los otros lenguajes orientados a objetos: asignando `null` al objeto.

```
$objMiObjeto=new MiObjecto();
    /*... uso del objeto*/
$objMiObjeto=null;
```

Ya está, PHP se encarga del resto.

Pero ¿y si la clase no tiene un método destructor escrito por mi?  No pasa absolutamente nada... dicho método es parte de los llamados *[métodos mágicos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.magic.php)*. Es más, es mejor que no intentes escribir el método destructor. [Este post](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/11/14/php-dont-call-the-destructor-explicitly/) recomienda no llamar nunca el método  destructor de forma explícita... el efecto puede ser totalmente lo contrario de lo esperado.

Comment: Por lo que entendí de tu respuesta apartir de PHP 7 ya no es necesario llamar al método mágico destructor de manera explicita, el objeto se destruye solo cuando ya no existan referencias al objeto ¿Es correcto?

Comment: En general sí, sobre todo hablando de clases que creas mediante `new`.  En otras los objetos se destruyen con sus propios métodos `close`, por ejemplo, las conexiones a `mysqli`, los prepared statement, etc.  Si de todos modos quieres destruirlos la forma correcta es estableciendo su valor a `null`.

Comment: Tengo una clase User con algunos métodos estáticos para crear objetos de los usuarios de la tabla, y para crear nuevos usuarios. Además tiene el método remove(), que elimina al usuario de la tabla y me gustaría destruir ese objeto despues invocar remove(), pero hacer $this = null no funciona. ¿Como podría hacer?

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres está dicho al final de la respuesta: `$objMiObjeto=null;` destruiría la instancia de ese objeto, @ManuAlvarado22. Aunque como también he dicho, no es necesario, ya que el objeto se destruye cuando no hay más referencia a él, generalmente cuando se sale del script/función que lo está usando.